# LMD (Linux Malware detect), inotify process not found Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, inotify

I'm using Linux Malware Detect and it's really awesome. I run the recent maldet script 4 times a day but I want to get the monitor going since it's a shared host server.

If I run maldet -m /home i will get the following error:

```
maldet(19604): {mon} no inotify process found, check /usr/local/maldetect/inotify/inotify_log for errors.
```

The problem is that the logfile is empty so I don't know how to get any further.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was strangling with same issue on a VPS with Plesk and CL linux (centos based) Its first time I answer so be gentle with me :)

My solution is not very professional but if you need to run maldet in monitor mode its a workaround hack (probably other based on this could give you better solutions)

So I did `nano /usr/local/maldetect/maldet` and found the line that contains $nice (its the only line that contains the search term $nice at around line 1318 )

there where 2 reasons it was not running

1. for some reason the `/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches` was set to `0` before it run this command :( so I added before $notice the line

   ```
   echo 100000 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
   ```

   100000 can be lower too if its too low you get errors like this

   ```
   Apr 15 13:38:38 plesk2 inotifywait[889842]: Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
   Apr 15 13:38:38 plesk2 inotifywait[889842]: Failed to watch /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs; upper limit on inotify watches reached!
   ```

   in `/var/log/messages` (search for them like this: `grep inotify /var/log/messages`).
2. For some strange reason (people that know bash much better please enlighten us) the command executed by the $nice line was

   ```
   /bin/nice -n 10 /usr/local/maldetect/inotify/inotifywait -d -r -o /usr/local/maldetect/inotify/inotify_log --fromfile /usr/local/maldetect/sess/inotify.paths.864367 --exclude (^/var/tmp/mysql.sock$|^/tmp/mysql.sock$|^/var/cache/buagent/md0.cache.data$|^/var/tmp/#sql_.*\.MYD$|^/tmp/#sql_.*\.MYD$) --timefmt %d %b %H:%M:%S --format %w%f %e %T -m -e create,move,modify
   ```

   and bash or sh was not satisfied with the  `--exclude (^/var/tmp/mysql.sock$|^/tmp/mysql.sock$|^/var/cache/buagent/md0.cache.data$|^/var/tmp/#sql_.*\.MYD$|^/tmp/#sql_.*\.MYD$)` part so I just removed from that line the $exclude (I know its bad but am working on this If I find it I will post back)

   so line

   ```
   $nice -n $inotify_nice $inotify -d -r -o $inotify_log --fromfile $inotify_fpaths $exclude --timefmt "%d %b %H:%M:%S" --format "%w%f %e %T" -m -e create,move,modify >> /dev/null 2>&1 &
   ```

   was changed to

   ```
   $nice -n $inotify_nice $inotify -d -r -o $inotify_log --fromfile $inotify_fpaths --timefmt "%d %b %H:%M:%S" --format "%w%f %e %T" -m -e create,move,modify >> /dev/null 2>&1 &
   ```

   And it worked

Also specially for plesk users I found this very help full

```
mysql -ss -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` psa -e "select www_root from hosting;" > /usr/local/maldetect/maldetfilelist
```

You can then start LMD with:

```
maldet -m /usr/local/maldetect/maldetfilelist
```

the above was found here: http://www.coredump.id.au/linux-malware-detect-debian-and-plesk/

Extra bonus if you want to see what bash is executing put this before the line you want (in our case the $nice line):

```
set -x
$nice -n $inotify_nice $inotify -s -d -r -o $inotify_log --fromfile $inotify_fpaths --timefmt "%d %b %H:%M:%S" --format "%w%f %e %T" -m -e create,move,modify >> /dev/null 2>&1 & set +x
```

the magic here is the beautiful set -x (to not see hundreds of line of debugging I put right after `set +x`)

sorry for being so descriptive and my bad English hope it helps you or anyone else

UPDATE if you change anything in the maldet file there is a cron running daily in (`/etc/cron.daily/maldet`) and more specific the line

```
/usr/local/maldetect/maldet -d >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

the above line every time find that md5 of file maldet has changed and re-installs the original one :( so I just comment it out :) and monitor works now without stopping every night :)

cheers 
sassm430

Comment: Using `$nice` rather than just running `nice` is an antipattern -- a bad practice best avoided. Same thing for the way inotify is wrapped, and all the unquoted expansions. (Try running these scripts through http://shellcheck.net/ for pointers on improvements).

Comment: Thank you for the tip (shellcheck.net), I will try it, regarding this case unfortunately its a open source project for Malware detection located here https://www.rfxn.com/projects/linux-malware-detect/ 
Linux Malware Detect (LMD) is a malware scanner for Linux released under the GNU GPLv2 license, that is designed around the threats faced in shared hosted environments. It uses threat data from network edge intrusion detection systems...... (more on the site of the project)

So not much we can do the good think is it does not update the core very often :)
once again thank you for your tips

Answer (score 0):

Thanks sassm430,

Your specific walkthrough didn't help BUT you posted your sources (http://www.coredump.id.au/linux-malware-detect-debian-and-plesk/) and I found this:

sed -i -e"s/\$inspath/inotify/inotifywait//usr/bin/inotifywait/" /usr/local/maldetect/internals.conf

You could also edit the /usr/local/maldetect/internals.conf manually and edit this line at the bottom:

inotify=$inspath/inotify/inotifywait

change the above line to:

inotify=/usr/bin/inotifywait

Now the monitor is running, I uploaded a file that have been quarantined but it does not seem to work, or how does the monitor work?

Does the monitor start it self on a reboot?

EDIT: I've executed the following command: maldet -m users

Answer (score 0):

@Jonathan Lindgren

For me the 
inotify=$inspath/inotify/inotifywait

change the above line to:

inotify=/usr/bin/inotifywait

did not work

Am not an expert on maldet bu the only think I can tell you are the following

1) I have not used maldet users or something like this I did (on a plesk) 
mysql -ss -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` psa -e "select www_root from hosting;" > /usr/local/maldetect/maldetfilelist

You can then start LMD with:

maldet -m /usr/local/maldetect/maldetfilelist

This creates a file from plesk with all the paths

An alternative would be to use something like this

maldet --m /var/www/vhosts/ or maldet --m/var/www/vhosts/?/somesubfolder where ? means all its like * on bash :)

2) another reason I can think of is, are you sure inotify is running? maybe you run out of inotify watchers do a 
cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
right after you have rum monitor.
Or just do a tail -f on a log file if you get something no more space left on device bla bla bla then you probably have run out of inotify watcher

But it would help if you tell us your distro etc etc  as mentioned in my original post I am using it on a centos with cloud linux and plesk and had this problem BUT on a centos with cloudlinux and cpanel it worked out of the box :( (till today I cant figure out why)

Also I strongly suggest you use the 
set -x

$nice -n $inotify_nice $inotify -s -d -r -o $inotify_log --fromfile $inotify_fpaths --timefmt "%d %b %H:%M:%S" --format "%w%f %e %T" -m -e create,move,modify >> /dev/null 2>&1 &

set +x

put this in  maldet file (before and after the $nice line) it will  really tell you if everything was executed correctly or not :)

UPDATE: also please check the update I did on the bottom of the 1st answer it might be you are hit by that (in that case monitor stops)
Also you could run a small script to check if monitor and inotifywatch are running and restart them if not.

hope you can use any of this and if I can help further please let me know.